# add rules to .aff file solr4.9

Tags: solr, addition, affix

I'm trying to add some rules to my es_ES.aff file.
I don't know why they are not being used.

I have the following in the schema:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!--La sgte linea hace que la búsqueda lo haga no solo por la palabra exacta... por ahora busca desde 4 letras minimo -->
    <!-- <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/> -->
    <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory"
      dictionary="es_ES.dic"
      affix="es_ES.aff"
      ignoreCase="true"
      strictAffixParsing="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <!-- Spanish accents ignores -->
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory"
      dictionary="es_ES.dic"
      affix="es_ES.aff"
      ignoreCase="true"
      strictAffixParsing="true" />
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <!-- Spanish accents ignores -->
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <!--La sgte linea hace que la búsqueda lo haga no solo por la palabra exacta... por ahora busca desde 4 letras minimo -->
    <!-- <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/> -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and in es_ES.aff i added

REP orzanizaciun orzanización because i want to replace orzanizaciun with orzanización

but i search by orzanizaciun, solr don't return any result.

what is wrong?

Another question: 
if the rule SFX R 0 ía [aei]r exists and i want to add below that one this rule SFX R 0 ia [aei]r
solr don't start ... it thows this error

Unable to create core: collection1
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load core configurati
on for core collection1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I discovered why solr thorws that error.
Its because in the beginning of each rule you have to add how many lines are contained in that rule. So my problem was that i didn't increment that number after i added a line.

:)